# Why is my scroll not happening?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing

I have a scroll method which works in most instances, but I have an instance where it is not scrolling.

This is the method:

```
public static void scrollPanelUp(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {

    debug.print(thisClass + " scrolling up...");

    try {
        // Create instance of Javascript executor
        JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        // now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is appeared
        // on page.

        je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

        debug.print(thisClass + " scrolled up!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(thisClass + " error in scrollPanelUp: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it is not scrolling in this instance?

Comment: To call this a Javascript issue is a little bit of a stretch.  I believe you want to have more detail, and maybe it should be tagged as Java and/or Selenium? I would suggest new tags, but I think you need more/better context to get any help with this.

Comment: I do not really understand 'context' in this case. I got it working by approaching my testcase from a different angle. It is highly possible that I was trying to scroll to an element that is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code available, I would start by looking at the element you are passing. if it isn't scrolling to the element, i would suggest that it isn't on the page. However outside of that, without HTML it is trying to scroll, or the code that is calling it. it is very hard to diagnose the issue.

However, Here is a code snipit i've used in the past hat has worked for me:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```